# Bootstrap class order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap in a team to structure a project.

I've always used bootstrap like so:

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

With a 'row' class inside a 'container' class.

This looks like the way described in the documentation.

A member of the team has post code like so.

With the 'conatiner' inside the 'row'

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-sm-12">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I'm new to the team was wanted to check if I was correct in thinking the it should be container > row and not row > container.

Any ideas if I'm right or it can be either way.

Comment: No it can't be either way, use the docs and read the comment under the answer.

Comment: ["Only columns (`.col-*-*`) may be children of `.row`s"](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E013)

Answer (score 1):

Container>row>column is proper. Your question kinda looks like you are asking us to confirm the documentation.